# Can't use props in a component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I made mapDispatchToProps, but when outputting to a component in the form "this.props" I get the error "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined". Although if I do console.log in the MapDispatchToprops itself, I get the value I need

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.App}>
                {routes}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
let routes = (
    <Switch>
        <PageHeader/>
        <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path='/News' component={NewsPage}/>
        <Route path='/Auth' component={Auth}/>
    </Switch>
)
debugger
if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
   routes = (
        <div>
            <PageHeader/>
            <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
            <Route path='/News' component={NewsPage}/>
            <Route path='/Auth' component={Auth}/>
            <Route path='/Logout' component={Logout}/>
        </div>
)
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log(state.auth.token)
    return {
        isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.token
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App)
```

Comment: Why do you define routes outside of `App` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your brace "}" isn't in the good place:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.App}>
                {routes}
            </div>
        )
    }
//You closed the brace here, it's wrong
let routes = (
    <Switch>
        <PageHeader/>
        <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path='/News' component={NewsPage}/>
        <Route path='/Auth' component={Auth}/>
    </Switch>
)
debugger
if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
   routes = (
        <div>
            <PageHeader/>
            <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
            <Route path='/News' component={NewsPage}/>
            <Route path='/Auth' component={Auth}/>
            <Route path='/Logout' component={Logout}/>
        </div>
)
}
}//the brace must be here

function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log(state.auth.token)
    return {
        isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.token
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App)
```